# how to use php code in css file

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am in middle of creating a Wordpress theme. I want to customize many CSS things from user. I want those changes to be done on CSS file upon user selection. I know how to import/include a CSS file using PHP code but not understanding how to use with Wordpress.

Can somebody help please?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing magical about it:

css.php

```
<?php

header('Content-type:text/css');
$color = 'puce';
?>

body {
   color: <?php echo $color ?>;
}
```

html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ref="css.php" type="text/css" />
```

or... as you say in the comments blow, you can't use a .php-named css file, then

theme.css

```
@import url('theme.php');
```

theme.php:

```
... code as above ...
```

Comment: So there would be 2 link attributes? One for style.css and another for css.php as described above. Correct?

Comment: No, you replace style.css with style.php.  You simply rename your stylesheet.

Comment: But if I rename styles.css by style.php Wordpress will not recognize this theme.

Comment: @Prashant layout your CSS in a separate style.php as suggested.  Then have your style.css file [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/@import) the PHP file.

Comment: @prashant: see edit above.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I will try this and update here

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can add this to an `htaccess` file to interpret CSS files with the PHP script handler:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .css
```

However, I recommend Marc B's solution because it doesn't require `htaccess`.

Comment: Should really be avoided as technically without then expressing the `content-type` header a *.css* file will then be served as `text/html` - as a project changes it's pretty much inevitable that this will be overlooked.

Comment: @Emissary Agreed. I use Marc B's method, myself.

Answer (score 0):

At any rate, while the other two answers are perfectly valid.  IF what you want to do is use Variables to pre-define some values.  You should look into [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).  SASS allows for variables, nested rules and more.